# Search on a form that is filtered with a combobox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form called LookUpByStore that displays records from a query. The records are products that we carry in our chain of retail stores. I have a combobox at the top of the form called StoreCombo that lists the store numbers as text. ("109", "111", etc.)

I have a textbox called txtSearch and a button called SearchBtn. I wrote the code below to fetch the store number from the StoreCombo and then search for products within that store only. The columns involved are:

StoreNum - which is chosen in the combobox

and then I need to search these three columns for whatever is entered in the textbox:

ItemNameWeight - which is a text field

ItemNum - which is a number

ItemUPCCode -  which is text

Here is my code currently, which I understand searches the ItemNameWeight AND sets the StoreNum, while the ItemNum and ItemUPCCode are searched without the storenum being set. I had this set as a macro, which worked, but I need to add the StoreNum to the other two fields as well, so it will go over the 255 character limit for macros.

```
[StoreNum]=[Forms]![LookupByStore]![StoreCombo] And [ItemNameWeight] Like "*" & [Forms]![LookupByStore]![txtSearch] & "*" Or [ItemNum] Like "*" & [Forms]![LookupByStore]![txtSearch] & "*" Or [ItemUPCCode] Like "*" & [Forms]![LookupByStore]![txtSearch]
```

I tried to move the code to VBA like this:

```
Private Sub SearchBtn_Click()
   DoCmd.ApplyFilter , [StoreNum] = [Forms]![LookupByStore]![StoreCombo] And [ItemNameWeight] Like "*" & [Forms]![LookupByStore]![txtSearch] & "*" Or [ItemNum] Like "*" & [Forms]![LookupByStore]![txtSearch] & "*" Or [ItemUPCCode] Like "*" & [Forms]![LookupByStore]![txtSearch] & "*"
End Sub
```

But this gives me an error 2427 "You entered an expression that has no value"

A) What am I doing wrong

and

B) What is the best practice to add StoreNum to the other two columns in VBA, because I know writing, "[StoreNum] = [Forms]![LookupByStore]![StoreCombo] And " each time is not the correct way to do it.

Thanks,
 Tony

Comment: I suggest you add a 'Debug.Print' of your filter and see what you have. Your syntax is wrong for text fields - you need something like: ItemNameWeight Like "'*" & [Forms]![LookupByStore]![txtSearch] & "*'" ...  Plus, you need to get your AND / OR logic grouped properly like: StoreNum = 'xxx' AND (ItemNameWeight like "*xx*" OR ItemUPCCode Like "*UUU*" or ItemNum Like 1234)  [you need to fix ItemNum filter to use numerics]

Answer (score 0):

Review [ApplyFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197651.aspx)

You need to enclose literal text within quote marks and concatenate with variables. Text fields requires apostrophe delimiters. All those [ ] are not really needed in this case as none of the names have spaces nor punctuation/special characters nor or are reserved words.

I've never used ApplyFilter method. I set form Filter and FilterOn properties. Review [Allen Browne Search](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html)

Also, you are using AND and OR operators. Correct parenthesizing is critical - `This AND THIS OR THIS` is not the same as `This AND (This OR This)`. Since you are using wildcard, I think you should just use AND operator. Wildcard really only works well with text type fields.

If the code is behind the referenced form, can use the Me alias.

`DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "StoreNum = " & Me.StoreCombo & " AND ItemNameWeight Like '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*' AND ItemNum Like '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*' AND ItemUPCCode Like '*" & Me.xtSearch & "*'"`